# Transitioning jQuery's .each to Javascript's .forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to switch from jQuery to learning more about Javascript without help from a jQuery library. I have an array of books to go through and write out the html of it, but it's not able to read the title or date or anything..

In jQuery, I can do this:

```
var books = [
    {name: 'Book 1', author: 'John Wriggly', pages: 9},
    {name: 'Book 2', author: 'James Wriggly', pages: 500},
    {name: 'Book 3', author: 'Jacob Wriggly', pages: 52}
]; 

$(books).each(function(index, item){
    console.log(item.name); // works! 
});
```

But without jQuery, I try this, and it returns undefined...

```
var books = [
    {name: 'Book 1', author: 'John Wriggly', pages: 9},
    {name: 'Book 2', author: 'James Wriggly', pages: 500},
    {name: 'Book 3', author: 'Jacob Wriggly', pages: 52}
]; 

books.forEach(function(index, item){
    console.log(item.name); // undefined :(
})
```

None of the properties work. Author, pages, etc.... What am I missing?

**Edit**: Not sure why so many down votes on both the question and the community supplied answers. It's a clear and concise question, with code examples of what works and what doesn't. The answers were also, clear, concise, and helpful. Sure, it's a simple question with a simple answer, but I had a difficult time finding the answer. Some of you clowns need to be more open to helping new-comers. Thanks to those who provided constructive input.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach `arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {` your arguments are out of order.

Comment: your parameters on `forEach` are the opposite of what you expect...

Comment: Better transition to `for (const item of books)` or `for (const [index, item] of books.entries())`. Don't use `forEach`.

Comment: It was useful for me. The answer also got a down vote... :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the sequence of the parameter.

```
books.forEach(function(item, index){
    console.log(item.name);
    console.log(index);
});
```